# Help me understand the word 'deflect' in this sentence

Tags: homework, gre

> Belanger dances with an *undemonstrative panache* that draws one's attention as if by seeking to *deflect* it; through finesse and understatement, he manages to seem at once intensely present and curiously detached.

This is a question in my GRE text book. There are 2 blanks, and you can choose the words given  to best fit the blanks. I have put the correct words in the sentence, in *italic*.

I think I do not understand the phrase '...by seeking to deflect it'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the two choices (*undemonstrative panache* and *deflect*) go together is that *undemonstrative* emphasizes that the dancer **isn't attempting to show off** his talent.

Rather than draw in the audience's attention with dance moves that emphasize the skill they necessitate - that is, moves that make their technical difficulty visible to the audience - he dances subtly and smoothly, so that the audience perceives his performance to be effortless. (In fact, this demands even more effort - imagine trying to complete a difficult move, all the while revealing no physical or mental exertion.)

In this way, he is *deflecting* (pushing away) the type of attention his ability is capable of garnering. He's so good he *could* demand the audience's complete attention, but chooses instead to let it linger on the dance itself.

Answer (score 3):

If it means anything at all, it means that Belanger’s skill appears to be effortless. He *deflects* the audience's attention away from his technical ability and in so doing allows them to enjoy his peformance as a whole. This is the sort of prose that some writers indulge in when they don’t have very much of substance to say.

Comment: Agreed, especially on that last point..."undemonstrative panache" is especially egregious, in my opinion.

Comment: +1 just for the gripe. I can see where tough reading can be useful for the GRE. However the author could really do with taking a style pointer or two from this dancer he claims to admire so much.